# how to extracted updated string after calling string.gsub in lua?

Tags: string, file, lua

**Problem Description:**

HI there.  I'm trying to figure out how to use the lua function "string.gsub".  I've been reading the manual which says:

> This is a very powerful function and can be used in multiple ways.
>   Used simply it can replace all instances of the pattern provided with
>   the replacement. A pair of values is returned, the modified string and
>   the number of substitutions made. The optional fourth argument n can
>   be used to limit the number of substitutions made:

```
> = string.gsub("Hello banana", "banana", "Lua user")
Hello Lua user  1
> = string.gsub("banana", "a", "A", 2)  -- limit substitutions made to 2
bAnAna  2
```

### Question

When it says that a pair of values is returned; how do I get the new string value?

### Code

```
local email_filename = "/var/log/test.txt"
local email_contents_file_exists = function(filename)
     file = io.open(filename, "r")
     if file == nil then
          return false
     else
          file.close(file)
          return true
      end
end
local read_email_contents_file = function()
   print('inside the function')
   if not email_contents_file_exists(email_filename) then 
      return false
   end
   local f = io.open(email_filename, "rb")
   local content = f:read("*all")
   f:close()
   print(content)
   --content = string.gsub(content, '[username]', 'myusername')
   --local tmp {}
   --tmp = string.gsub(content, '[username]', 'myusername')
   print(string.gsub(content, '[username]', 'myusername'))
   return content
end
local test = read_email_contents_file()
```

**What I've Tried So Far:**

I've tried just printing the results, as you see above. That returns a bunch of garbled text. Tried saving to original string and I've also tried saving the results to an array (`local tmp = {}`)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were going pretty good with reading the Lua users wiki.

In Lua, when you a function returns more than one value, you can access them all as follows

```
function sth()
  return 1, "hi", false
end
x, y, z, a, b, c = sth() -- x = 1; y = "hi" and z = false(boolean); a = b = c = nil
```

Now, coming back to `string.gsub` function. It returns two values. The first being the processed string and the second being the number of time `gsub` performed itself on the input string.

So, to get the new string value, something like this would be best:

```
local tempString = string.gsub(content, '[username]', 'myusername')
```

OR

```
local tempString = content:gsub( '[username]', 'myusername' )
```

Ofcourse, here, you need to be aware about the various patterns used in Lua which are mentioned in the [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) book.

Answer (score 2):

```
> = string.gsub('banana', 'a', 'A', 2)
bAnAna  2
> = (string.gsub('banana', 'a', 'A', 2))
bAnAna
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape [ and ] because they are magic characters in Lua patterns.

Comment: It seems that escaping only `[` is enough.